# if an exploit is affecting MS office does it affect also LibreOffice?

Tags: security, libreoffice

This question is really annoying me a lot and I want a reasonable, certain, logical... response for it

Comment: While this question is very vague, it's also off topic. I don't see what this has to do with unix or linux. You could try http://security.stackexchange.com, but I recommend refining the question first.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic (i.e. ditto Patrick).  *Note that LibreOffice is cross-platform, so has nothing specific to do with Unix or Linux*.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's hard to give a concrete answer because your question is so abstract; if you asked about a *particular* vulnerability (say, by CVE number), then it'd be possible.

But, in general, there are several types of vulnerabilities, speaking broadly:

- Attacks that use standard features of the programs in the normal manner to fool humans. For example, its possible to set text to be visible on screen but not print, or vice versa. If you know a contract is going to be reviewed on screen, and then printed only for signing, you can get someone to sign something unknowingly. This will work in both office programs. (Consult a lawyer to determine if it'll work on your local court system—probably not.)
- Attacks that exploit implementation errors (bugs). For example, buffer overflows. There is a small chance of the exact same bug being in two independent programs, but the chance of the same exploit working is vanishingly small, as exploits often rely on the exact implementation. Since Office and LibreOffice are independent implementations, an Office exploit probably doesn't explot LibreOffice, and vice versa. An OpenOffice.org or Apache OpenOffice bug, however, is likely to work against LibreOffice, as those all are very similar implementations.
- Attacks that use the built-in scripting languages. To the extent LibreOffice implements the same scripting language, these will work. Neither program executes scripts without warning, I believe.
- Attacks on common protocols. For example, if someone broke the crypto algorithms used to digitally sign documents, that would apply to all implementations. (And potentially to a *lot* of other programs, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, no. MS Office and LibreOffice are completely independent programs, so the existence of an exploit against one doesn't lead to an exploit against the other.

Occasionally, the authors of the two programs may have made the same mistake implementing the same specification (the same file format, for these programs). It's rare, but it can happen.